# Query string to pre-select price field for events

Tags: civievent

On contribution pages, I've been able to do this for price sets e.g.

https://example.org/donate/?price_100=1035

However, I've not been able to get this to work on event pages? What's different and is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Contribution form has this code in the `setDefaultValues` function:

```
$priceFieldName = 'price_' . $values['price_field_id'];
$priceFieldValue = CRM_Price_BAO_PriceSet::getPriceFieldValueFromURL($this, $priceFieldName);
```

Direct link: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/aa513711eae7c32ad1cab2e9fd077fffefcf7217/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.php#L246

It should be possible to implement it for events too. Check out the `setDefaultValues` function in `CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Register.php`, inside the loop here:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/aa513711eae7c32ad1cab2e9fd077fffefcf7217/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Register.php#L301

I haven't tested it, but if it works for you, I would encourage you to send a pull-request so that it gets reviewed and tested, and eventually included in a future version. It's a useful feature indeed. I can also help with the PR.

Comment: PR: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/22313